# Is it possible to collect the data from logs in Elastic Search - Using Kibana and trigger a mail at daily interval

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

There is a situation where I need to collect data from logs - Say All the Internal Server Exceptions which occurs today from elastic search (Using kibana) and forward the collected data via mail daily (Like a Job).

Is it possible with kibana dashboard only?

If yes, What are the good resources to follow?

Answer (score 0):

### Ship logs to Elasticsearch and Trigger the Event-based emails from Kibana

- Filebeat or logstash
- Use Kibana and write the alerts based on the events getting indexed in ELasticsearch